# sending javascript variable with hidden input using jquery in modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So there are two modals with only one dropdown option. Second modal appears after the first one dropdown is selected. And after the selection in second dropdown i wanna submit the form with both dropdown inputs 
is this the right way to do it? Below is code of my second modal second modal

```
<div id="time_modal" class="modal">
    <form id="popup-form" action="some.php">
            <select name="timing" id="choose-timing" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="">something</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="demo_val" value="<?php echo '<script>$(function(){
            $("#first_modal_select").on("change",function(e){
            var locn1 = $( "#first_modal_select" ).val();}); document.write(locn1);                 
            </script>' ?>" id="demo_val"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to build an object from a form to send it to a server?

Comment: kind of yes. I just want the value that was selected in the previous modal to be passed as a hidden input by this form.

Comment: Well are you trying to to grab the value of a HTML class that doesn't exist on your form? I.e. #first_modal_select.

Comment: No there is another modal before this one which is identical. I am grabbing the option value of that modal. The first modal hides and this modal appears, and this modal on select takes the value of both modal to some.php.

Comment: Try `<form> <modal 1></m*1> <modal2> </m*2> </form>`. Per @MarcFreeman's answer, hide the second modal until you need it. This way all `<input>` elements are within the form and available in both modals, so when you send it (post/ajax), all the data is readily available.

Comment: That worked Nuke. Thanks , but it still does justify my above query.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you're trying to grab the value of a HTML element that doesn't yet exist and then trying to append it to the DOM.

I think you'll find what you're looking for here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_hidden_value

It's a vanilla JS implementation but you should be able to figure out the jQuery for this :) Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, i ll look into it. But am i doing it right in the above code?